# Can't import pytorch-lightning even though I've installed it

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, pip, pytorch-lightning

I tried to refactor my python code to use Pytorch-Lightning. However I've faced the problem that I can't import Pytorch-Lightning library. I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 14
     12 from fastai.vision.all import * 
     13 from ipywidgets import IntProgress 
---> 14 import pytorch_lightning as pl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_lightning'
```

It doesn't see pytorch_lightning and lightning when importing.

I have only one python environment and kernel(I'm using Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code).
When I check pip list, I get this output:

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ -------------
aiohttp                  3.8.4
aiosignal                1.3.1
anyio                    3.6.2
apturl                   0.5.2
arrow                    1.2.3
async-timeout            4.0.2
attrs                    22.2.0
Automat                  0.8.0
backcall                 0.1.0
bcrypt                   3.1.7
beautifulsoup4           4.12.0
bleach                   3.1.1
blessed                  1.20.0
blinker                  1.4
Brlapi                   0.7.0
certifi                  2022.12.7
chardet                  3.0.4
charset-normalizer       3.1.0
Click                    7.0
cloud-init               22.4.2
cmake                    3.26.1
colorama                 0.4.3
command-not-found        0.3
configobj                5.0.6
constantly               15.1.0
croniter                 1.3.8
cryptography             2.8
cupshelpers              1.0
dateutils                0.6.12
dbus-python              1.2.16
decorator                4.4.2
deepdiff                 6.3.0
defer                    1.0.6
defusedxml               0.6.0
distro                   1.4.0
distro-info              0.23ubuntu1
dnspython                2.3.0
duplicity                0.8.12.0
email-validator          1.3.1
entrypoints              0.3
fastapi                  0.88.0
fasteners                0.14.1
filelock                 3.11.0
frozenlist               1.3.3
fsspec                   2023.4.0
future                   0.18.2
h11                      0.14.0
html5lib                 1.0.1
httpcore                 0.16.3
httplib2                 0.14.0
httptools                0.5.0
httpx                    0.23.3
hyperlink                19.0.0
idna                     3.4
importlib-metadata       1.5.0
incremental              16.10.1
inquirer                 3.1.3
install                  1.3.5
ipykernel                5.2.0
ipython                  7.13.0
ipython_genutils         0.2.0
ipywidgets               6.0.0
itsdangerous             2.1.2
jedi                     0.15.2
Jinja2                   3.1.2
jsonpatch                1.22
jsonpointer              2.0
jsonschema               3.2.0
jupyter-client           6.1.2
jupyter-core             4.6.3
keyring                  18.0.1
language-selector        0.1
launchpadlib             1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient       0.14.2
lazr.uri                 1.0.3
lightning                2.1.0.dev0
lightning-cloud          0.5.32
lightning-utilities      0.8.0
lit                      16.0.0
lockfile                 0.12.2
louis                    3.12.0
macaroonbakery           1.3.1
Mako                     1.1.0
markdown-it-py           2.2.0
MarkupSafe               2.1.2
mdurl                    0.1.2
mistune                  0.8.4
monotonic                1.5
more-itertools           4.2.0
mpmath                   1.3.0
multidict                6.0.4
nbconvert                5.6.1
nbformat                 5.0.4
netifaces                0.10.4
networkx                 3.1
notebook                 6.0.3
numpy                    1.24.2
nvidia-cublas-cu11       11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11   11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11   11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11        8.5.0.96
nvidia-cufft-cu11        10.9.0.58
nvidia-curand-cu11       10.2.10.91
nvidia-cusolver-cu11     11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusparse-cu11     11.7.4.91
nvidia-nccl-cu11         2.14.3
nvidia-nvtx-cu11         11.7.91
oauthlib                 3.1.0
olefile                  0.46
ordered-set              4.1.0
orjson                   3.8.9
packaging                23.0
pandocfilters            1.4.2
paramiko                 2.6.0
parso                    0.5.2
pexpect                  4.6.0
pickleshare              0.7.5
Pillow                   7.0.0
pip                      23.0.1
prometheus-client        0.7.1
prompt-toolkit           2.0.10
protobuf                 3.6.1
psutil                   5.9.4
pyasn1                   0.4.2
pyasn1-modules           0.2.1
pycairo                  1.16.2
pycups                   1.9.73
pydantic                 1.10.7
Pygments                 2.14.0
PyGObject                3.36.0
PyHamcrest               1.9.0
PyJWT                    1.7.1
pymacaroons              0.13.0
PyNaCl                   1.3.0
pyOpenSSL                19.0.0
pyprof2calltree          1.4.4
pyRFC3339                1.1
pyrsistent               0.15.5
pyserial                 3.4
python-apt               2.0.1
python-dateutil          2.8.2
python-debian            0.1.36ubuntu1
python-dotenv            1.0.0
python-editor            1.0.4
python-multipart         0.0.6
pytorch-lightning        2.0.1
pytz                     2019.3
pyxdg                    0.26
PyYAML                   6.0
pyzmq                    18.1.1
ranger-fm                1.9.3
readchar                 4.0.5
reportlab                3.5.34
requests                 2.28.2
requests-unixsocket      0.2.0
rfc3986                  1.5.0
rich                     13.3.3
screen-resolution-extra  0.0.0
SecretStorage            2.3.1
Send2Trash               1.5.0
service-identity         18.1.0
setuptools               67.6.1
simplejson               3.16.0
six                      1.14.0
sniffio                  1.3.0
sos                      4.4
soupsieve                2.4
ssh-import-id            5.10
starlette                0.22.0
starsessions             1.3.0
sympy                    1.11.1
systemd-python           234
terminado                0.8.2
testpath                 0.4.4
torch                    2.0.0
torchmetrics             0.11.4
tornado                  5.1.1
tqdm                     4.65.0
traitlets                5.9.0
triton                   2.0.0
Twisted                  18.9.0
typing_extensions        4.5.0
ubuntu-advantage-tools   8001
ubuntu-drivers-common    0.0.0
ufw                      0.36
ujson                    5.7.0
unattended-upgrades      0.1
urllib3                  1.26.15
usb-creator              0.3.7
uvicorn                  0.21.1
uvloop                   0.17.0
wadllib                  1.3.3
watchfiles               0.19.0
wcwidth                  0.1.8
webencodings             0.5.1
websocket-client         1.5.1
websockets               10.4
wheel                    0.40.0
widgetsnbextension       2.0.0
xkit                     0.0.0
yarl                     1.8.2
zipp                     1.0.0
zope.interface           4.7.1
```

As you can see, there is a Pytorch-Lightning library installed, however even when I uninstall, reinstall with newest version, install again through GitHub repository, updated,  nothing works. What seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The API of newest version of pl has been changed.
You can try:

```
import lightning as pl
```

Answer (score 0):

moving forward with PyTorch Lightning 2.0, correct way to import is -

```
import lightning L

class Model(L.LightningModule):
    ...

trainer = L.Trainer(max_epochs=1)
trainer.fit(Model(), dataloader)
```

We also published an upgrade guide [here](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/latest/upgrade/migration_guide.html)